# Filter models by ManyToMany relationship with Django User

Tags: python, django

Given this model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.admin import User

# Create your models here.
class Plan(models.Model):
    editors = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

in which every plan can have more than one editor (User), how can I retrieve all plans for which a particular user is one of the editors?

Something like this?

```
Plan.objects.filter(editors__contains(request.user))
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use the normal equals here.

```
Plan.objects.filter(editors=request.user)
```